# Point me to some open source projects *with* (unit) tests

Tags: unit-testing

For reference, I'm looking for some open source projects with unit tests.

**Edit** -  *Surely* there *must* be more!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[SQLite has a very comprehensive test suite](http://www.sqlite.org/testing.html).  It may not be *unit* testing, per se, but it is quite comprehensive.

> As of version 3.6.16 (all statistics
>   in the report are against that release
>   of SQLite), the SQLite library
>   consists of approximately 63.9 KSLOC
>   of C code. (KSLOC means thousands of
>   "Source Lines Of Code" or, in other
>   words, lines of code excluding blank
>   lines and comments.) By comparison,
>   the project has 709 times as much test
>   code and test scripts - 45385.9 KSLOC.

Comment: They automatically generate those stats on the web page with each new release.  That makes my programmer insides feel warm and fuzzy. :)

Comment: This fuzziness is infectious :)

Answer (score 2):

[OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/) has a very comprehensive set of conformance tests that are required to pass in order to be considered a valid implementation of Java. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The ASP.NET MVC Project, whose source code can be seen on codeplex, has a very complete set of unit tests.  It can even be browsed online :-)

http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/BrowseLatest

Answer (score 2):

[Spring](http://www.springframework.org) is loaded with JUnit tests.

Comment: Plus the PetStore, which could be thought of as a functional test

Answer (score 1):

A few examples:

- [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) (java) has good test coverage. You can view them online in their [repository](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/tree/master/lucene/core/src/test/org/apache/lucene).
- [Testability explorer](https://code.google.com/archive/p/testability-explorer/) is a java utility to measure how testable source code is written by [Misko Hevery](http://misko.hevery.com/about/), testing guru at google. The source code for it is naturally incredibly well tested itself.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) has a bunch. You can see when they fail on their [CI](http://bamboo.ci.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS) server.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) libraries have unit tests, so do many of the implementations of [Google Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/)

Answer (score 1):

[Ruby On Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) has lots of unit tests, and most of the popular extensions (plugins/gems) have unit tests as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com) projects to be open source, then look at the [Service Factory](http://www.codeplex.com/servicefactory). There were over 700 tests in there when I extended the source last year.

Answer (score 1):

All the [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org) tools have good amount of tests.

Selenium core and Selenium IDE have jsunit tests and Selenium RC has JUnit tests. The source code can be found [here](http://seleniumhq.org/download/source.html)

Answer (score 1):

Mark Pilgrim's [Feedparser](http://www.feedparser.org/) bills itself thusly:

> Parse RSS and Atom feeds in Python.
>   3000 unit tests. Open source.

Answer (score 0):

[Chestnut Package Manager](http://chestnut.sourceforge.net) *(advertisement)*

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find some Open Source projects which had some type of unit testing.  But watch out for what you are trying to do with that information.  Remember an Open Source project is a collaborative work between developers.  Code goes around back and for and several people take a look at it before the code is even compiled in for final release. So, even when unit testing is not predominant in most open source projects, the quality of the code is guaranteed by the peer review/testing done by several people at the time.

On the other hand, on common enterprise projects you have a group of developers, each one working in a specific part of code and interacting between other developers methods and functions.  Since only a few very busy people are looking at the big picture Unit Tests are a must on those projects.  So, when a developer put something new, we needs to be aware that we does not broke somebody else code.  On open source project, that somebody will probably send you a nasty e-mail as soon as he installed your patch.

Just be aware that both techniques should not be compared side by side.

Comment: I disagree with your conclusion: that tests are not as important in open source. Not having tests hinders novice contributors from making changes without fear of regression.

Answer (score 0):

The [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/index.php) unit testing framework has code to test **itself**. I'm sure the same is true for all other unit testing frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

My project [JMockit](https://jmockit.dev.java.net) (a toolkit for developer testing, particularly for unit testing with mocks) contains a good number of tests, mostly using JUnit 4.

[This](https://jmockit.dev.java.net/source/browse/jmockit/samples/TimingFramework/test/org/jdesktop/animation/timing) sample test suite, for example, contains 150+ unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

The Factor programming language has around 42 thousand lines in its test files.

Answer (score 0):

All of my open source projects have unit tests:

1. [Unquote](http://code.google.com/p/unquote/): http://code.google.com/p/unquote/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FUnquoteTests
2. [FsEye](http://code.google.com/p/fseye/): http://code.google.com/p/fseye/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FTest.FsEye
3. [NL](http://code.google.com/p/nl-compiler/): http://code.google.com/p/nl-compiler/source/browse/#hg%2FTest.NL