# Good open-source codebase for learning refactoring

Tags: refactoring

What open-source codebases have you used to learn refactoring, written in either java or C# ? One requirement is good unit tests.

Comment: As an alternative to refactoring an existing codebase, consider practicing Code Katas. See http://codingdojo.org/

Comment: For project with unit tests, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210479/point-me-to-some-open-source-projects-with-unit-tests. But this question should be CW in my opinion, I doubt there will be a single answer.

Comment: I'm curious: Why do you require open-source codebases to learn refactoring? Why not use the the codebases you have already, be they work-related, or personal projects?

Answer (score 0):

A code that accompanies my "Professional Refactoring in C# ans ASP .NET" book includes a sample application that is refactored throughout the book and you can observe how it evolves. You can download the sample code [here.](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-Refactoring-in-C-ASP-NET.productCd-047043452X,descCd-DOWNLOAD.html) Note: does not include unit tests.